# validate the user input to be in this format "ABC123" isvalid boolean

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, swig

I have a problem validating flightCode, I want to user the enter the flight code in this form ABC123

```
private void ValidationOfFlightCode(String flightCode)
{
    if (flightCode.length()== 6)
    {
        boolean isvalid = Regex.IsMatch(flightCode, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$");
        if (isvalid)
        {
            boolean isLetter = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                isLetter = Char.IsLetter(flightCode, i);
                if (!isLetter)
                    break;
            }
            if (isLetter)
            {
                System.err.println(flightCode + ": " + isvalid);
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what problem you are facing (beside fact that this code doesn't look like Java since there is no standard `Regex` class condaining `IsMatch` method in this language)?

Comment: I'm confused on what your actual problem is

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Char.IsLetter(flightCode, i)` check? You've already checked, that the input is in the correct format.

Comment: What is the link with swig ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
private void ValidationOfFlightCode(String flightCode){
   boolean isValid = flightCode.matches("^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$");
   System.out.println(flightCode + ": " + isValid);
}
```

Basically the rest of your code is unnecessary because the regex already contains 6 chars requirement and the specified format (3 capital letters and then 3 numbers).
More sense would make:

```
private boolean validateFlightCode(String flightCode){
   boolean isValid = flightCode.matches("^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$");
   //System.out.println(flightCode + ": " + isValid);
   return isValid;
}
```

The second option returns the validation result as well. Also the method naming is according to Java coding conventions and is better readable, because you aren't actually describing the process (validation), but action (validate).

EDIT: use `"^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$"` for uppercase letters only, `"^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}$"` for lowercase only, `"^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$"` for mixed and `"^([A-Z]|[a-z]){3}[0-9]{3}$"` for either ones.

Comment: Hard to tell if OP want uppercase letters only or not. Maybe add an information that he had to determine that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, added additional info on different regex formatting.